# Streaming audio from a socket on Android using AudioTrack

Tags: android, sockets, streaming

I'm trying to play a PCM stream using the AudioTrack class. This is the code:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 20000, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.play();
// Reading data.
byte[] data = new byte[200];
int n = 0;
try {
   while ((n = s.getInputStream().read(data)) != -1)
      audioTrack.write(data, 0, n);
}
catch (IOException e) {
   return;
}
```

Unfortunately, the audio I get is continuously interrupted. I tried to write down data in a file instead of writing to the audioTrack, and playing it with aplay. It seems it is perfect. No interruption. Is there anything wrong in the code I reported when using audioTrack? Or maybe simply the data is not arriving in time?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a few checks:

1. Use your code to read a file. Just open file as a stream.
2. Measure throughput. Every time a chunk of data arrives, record time (`System. nanoTime()`) and length. Then you could calculate if data is arriving late.

Comment: I tried streaming a file and works perfectly. No interruptions. But, what should I conclude by computing the throughput? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting your data from, but it seems that AudioTrack consumes data faster then you are receiving it.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the code in a separate thread with high priority.

`android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO)`

In the run() of the thread read and write the data.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the audio data from a variable latency stream and sending it to audioTrack.write in the same thread will work poorly as you've observed.  This is a job for 2 threads where one reads the data from the stream (and buffers a reasonable amount) while the other writes the audio data to the audioTrack object.  You could potentially get away with reading and writing large blocks of audio data at a time, but the audioTrack class imposes limitations on that.  When the audioTrack thread wakes up after a write operation, you cannot do significant work in that thread or you will cause gaps in the audio output; you must provide it with a continuous stream of data.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly: one thread reads from the socket, and places data somewhere, maybe in a shared queue? Or what other structure do you suggest? In the meantime, another thread iterates taking data from that buffer to the audioTrack. Is this what you were suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: In my implementation I just created my own FIFO from a word array and head/tail pointers.  The important thing is to have the audio data ready when audioTrack.write is ready to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `AudioTrack` before, but comparing your version with [this implementation](http://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/source/browse/trunk/android/streaming_audio/src/rmd/media/StreamingAudio/Main.java) the main difference I see is that you are creating your `AudioTrack` with a different buffersize than you are using for your own buffer:  `20000` vs `200`.  I'd try using the same size for both.

Comment: I tried that already with some different values. I always get interruptions.